# correctly insert chart from Google Sheet into Document using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to copy charts from my spreadsheet to a document using Google apps script.
Inserting the charts works, but there is an issue with a) permissions and b) formatting.

Charts can be inserted as follows:

```
var b = d.getBody();
var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("charts").getCharts();
for (var i in charts) {
  b.appendImage(charts[i]);
  Logger.log(charts[i].getBlob().getName()); // correct: "chart.png"
}
```

- When I manually copy the chart and paste it in the document, the formatting is exactly as in the spreadsheet.
- when I copy using the script, formatting looks very strange or even causes an error (for the line chart with dates on the x-axis it shows an image with the text `Data column(s) for axis #1 cannot be of type string`)

Top row is manually copied, bottom row is the result of the script.
[image: manual and script]

The second -related?- issue: the spreadsheet needs to be shared ("anyone with the link can view"), otherwise it shows the image (correct name, width, height, etc.) as an error message: `User not signed-in. Sign in`.

Any suggestions how to insert the chart with the correct formatting and without having to share the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stefan pointed me in the right direction (thanks!).
It appears the rendering is done quite differently when pasting/saving images.
Different axis settings, colors, theme, etc.

I ended up manually creating the chart. E.g. for the first bar chart, the following results in a chart that appears the same in the spreadsheet and in the document:

```
var chart = dest.newChart();
chart
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
  .addRange(myrange)  
  .setPosition(2,8,0,0)
  .setOption("theme","maximized")
  .setOption("colors",["#3366CC","#FF9900","#DC3912","#109618"])
  .setOption('isStacked', true)
  .setOption('width', 500)
  .setOption('height', 130)
  .setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', countActions)
  .setOption('vAxis.gridlines.count', 0)
  .setOption('legend', {position: 'in', textStyle: {fontSize: 12}})

var chart = chart.build();
dest.insertChart(chart);
```

I also had to change the data range, as it appears the following chart settings can not be set manually.

- switch rows/columns
- use first row as header

To solve that I have manually transposed the range in the spreadsheet (`=TRANSPOSE(original_range)`) and let `myrange` point to that new range, and I have added an empty column so that one is used as an empty header.

I have not looked at the line chart yet, it could be the Chart API can not create a timeline in the same way as the Spreadsheet does.

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth I just used the original script in a simple report builder that takes data and charts from a Google Sheet and auto-generates a report containing them for any user. It worked very easily. Was a slightly modified version of the following

```
var charts = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("charts").getCharts();
for (var i in charts) {
  doc.getBody.appendImage(charts[i]);
  Logger.log(charts[i].getBlob().getName())};
```

where in my script "doc" is a var that repr

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
[Reading title of Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124708/reading-title-of-graph)

When I was playing around, I remember having issues as well like you described. When I made sure all the required fields were added in the graph (so no skipping of data elements), it worked fine.

Strangly, skipping data elements didn't seem to cause issues in the graph (neither with manually copying & pasting).

Comment: Hoi Stefan, what is the definition of "required fields"?

Comment: Like, you can have a column with 1,2,4,5,6 and create a pie. However, officially a pie needs two columns a,b,c,d,e and 1,2,3,4,5. 

The same goes with some other graphs. You can make them without entering all the official required columns, but this gave me a headache with showing the graphs as I intended. Once I added all the 'official' required columns, it worked.

Have a look at https://support.google.com/drive/topic/1361474?hl=en&ref_topic=2811806, select a graph and read Data format.