# Import google spreadsheet data to google doc app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying google app script to import google spreadsheet data to google doc. I haven't found any help in checking the API. Is it possible to import data to doc? then how?

Comment: Do you want an image of the spreadsheet?  Do you want a table in the Doc, with data from the spreadsheet?  Do you want a working spreadsheet inside of a Google Doc?  You can get data out of the spreadsheet, and create a table in a Doc with code.

Comment: I have a google spreadsheet with data and graph and would like to plot on google word Document.

Comment: So, you want to put a graph into a Google Doc?  Not the actual data?

Comment: yes,,i need to put graph on google word doc

Comment: An image can be inserted into a Doc.  I don't see anything in the documentation for inserting a chart.  You might need to convert a chart to an image, then insert the image?  You can "manually" insert a chart.

Comment: See this stackoverflow post:  [Insert Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830086/correctly-insert-chart-from-google-sheet-into-document-using-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks Sandy...is it possible to show a dynamic chart on web app. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, the web app is done in HTML, CSS and client side JavaScript.  The client side JavaScript can be written to make a chart dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

```
 function createDocFromSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet =  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);

  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
for(n=2;n<=values.length;++n){
  var cell = sheet.getRange(n,3).getValue();
    var row = sheet.getRange(n,2,1,5).getValues();
var newDoc = DocumentApp.create(cell);
 var body = newDoc.getBody();
  body.insertParagraph(0,row);
 newDoc.saveAndClose(); 
}
}
```