# Inserting a Bar Chart into a Google Doc using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps script to build a Google Doc from data I have in a Google sheet. I'd like to use Google apps script to build a bar chart from some of the data in the spreadsheet. I've figured out how to generate the chart, but I don't see how to insert the chart into the actual document.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830086/correctly-insert-chart-from-google-sheet-into-document-using-google-apps-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correctly insert chart from Google Sheet into Document using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830086/correctly-insert-chart-from-google-sheet-into-document-using-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

If you've built the chart using apps script; Charts service then you can insert it as an image. There might be a better way of doing though.

```
  var myChartBlob = myChart.getAs('image/png').copyBlob();
  var myChartImage = docBody.appendImage(myChartBlob);
```